# Unlock LUKS device in dropbear-initramfs remotely, How to solve network card driver problems?

Tags: luks, initramfs, dropbear

I want to Unlock LUKS device in dropbear-initramfs remotely, I have 3 network card:

1,I219-LM

2,USB 8156B

3,Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW

All of them work well in Debian 12, but in dropbear-initramfs only I219-LM can work. How to make "USB 8156B" and "Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW" work in  dropbear-initramfs?